# Ember -- Serializing Array into URL

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm serializing an array (not the model) into dynamic path segments.  While Ember is doing the transition, it looks like it's forcing the model to become the array that was serialized.

I don't want it to do this.  How do I prevent the model from changing when I serialize the array into the URL?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to overide [deserialize](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_deserialize) method in route.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I don't see anything about a deserialize method in the link you provided.  I tried overriding it anyway, but it looks like it's the same thing as the model hook.

Comment: I decided to just make the model the array that I serialize to sidestep the issue.